# ASP .NET - Use asp:ListBox in ListView

Tags: asp.net, listview

In a ASP .NET 3.5 ListView **InsertItemTemplate** I would like to change a textbox:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("plant") %>' />
```

to a ListBox:

```
<asp:ListBox ID="list" runat="server" DataValueField='<%# Bind("plant") %>' >
```

How do I bind the field 'plant' to the listbox?

**UPDATE 1**

Here is a sample of using a combobox with the SelectedValue property:

```
<cc1:ComboBox ID="ComboBox1" AutoPostBack="false" 
     DropDownStyle="DropDownList" AutoCompleteMode="Suggest" 
     CaseSensitive="false" CssClass="AjaxToolkitStyle" 
     ItemInsertLocation="Append" 
     SelectedValue='<%# Bind("car") %>' runat="server">
   <asp:ListItem>Porsche</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem>VW</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem>BMW</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem>UNK</asp:ListItem>
</cc1:ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried [SelectedValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedvalue.aspx)?

```
<asp:ListBox ID="list" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("plant") %>' >
</asp:ListBox>
```

Comment: Is SelectedValue a valid property?  It doesn't show up in the IntelliSense autocomplete.

Comment: It doesn't show up in the intellisense in markup - but it is valid.  Same goes for DropDownList.

Answer (score 1):

```
<asp:ListBox ID="list" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text='<%# Bind("plant") %>'></asp:ListItem>
</asp:ListBox>
```

However, this will just populate the listbox with the one item, which I doubt is what you want.